# Issue creating pair on IUniswapV2Factory (sepolia)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, ether

I have the following interfaces in my contract file:

```
interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
}
```

I deploy my contract using remix to sepolia fine, transfer back the minted token and send some eth. I then want to trigger the following function in my contract :

```
function addLiquidityAndEnableTrading() external onlyOwner() {
    require(!tradingOpen,"trading is already open");       
    //sepolia router address
    uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0xB26B2De65D07eBB5E54C7F6282424D3be670E1f0);
    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _totalSupply);
    uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
    //uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(address(this),balanceOf(address(this)),0,0,owner(),block.timestamp);
    //IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), type(uint).max);
    //tradingEnabled = true;
}`
```

The reason the later lines of code in the function are commented out is that I isolated the issue to following line of code :

```
   uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

I'm struggling to work out the issue here and would appreciate any advice

EDIT: Switched to goerli and it worked!